# Custom Activity Designer(like FlowChart activity) in WF4.0

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity, activitydesigner

Is it possible to create a Custom activity, same as Flow Chart Activity?

As Flow Chart activity is a sealed class, we can not use it directly, so is it possible to place a Panel(for holding other activity) and the re-sizable grip in the expand view of the Custom activity, so that user can increase and decrease the size of the activity by dragging the corners of the activity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create any activity, or ActivityDesigner as you need, yourself. However the FlowChartDesigner is one of the more complex designers. As you noticed most WF4 classes are sealed so it would be quite a bit of work as you would have to rebuild it from the ground up.

Comment: Santosh, you can find examples here: 
http://wf.codeplex.com/
http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.com/2010/02/wf-40-custom-activity-designer.html